# ng-submit doesn't prevent submission

Tags: forms, angularjs, validation

There are a lot of similar questions on SO.  I've gone through many of them and not found my problem.

I have a form that is using `ng-submit`.  Unfortunately, pressing enter or clicking submit works even when the form is not valid.  The `ng-submit` method is called.

CodePen Sample : http://codepen.io/calendee/pen/tgFhq

```
<form name="testForm" novalidate ng-submit="submit()">

  <label for="firstname">First Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" ng-model="data.firstname" required="true" ng-minlength="4" ng-maxlength="10">

    <div class="errors">
      <p>firstname Errors:</p>
      <p ng-show="testForm.firstname.$error.required">firstname is required</p>
      <p ng-show="testForm.firstname.$error.minlength">firstname is too short</p>
      <p ng-show="testForm.firstname.$error.maxlength">firstname is too long</p>
    </div>              

    <label for="lastname">Last Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="lastname" ng-model="data.lastname" ng-required="true" ng-minlength="4" ng-maxlength="10">

    <div class="errors">
      <p>lastname Errors:</p>
      <p ng-show="testForm.lastname.$error.required">lastname is required</p>
      <p ng-show="testForm.lastname.$error.minlength">lastname is too short</p>
      <p ng-show="testForm.lastname.$error.maxlength">lastname is too long</p>
    </div>              


  <button class="button button-balanced" type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

If I change the form the `ng-form` the submit event does not work at all even when the form is valid.

CodePen Sample : http://codepen.io/calendee/pen/imJdc

```
<ng-form name="testForm" novalidate ng-submit="submit()">

  <label for="firstname">First Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" ng-model="data.firstname" required="true" ng-minlength="4" ng-maxlength="10">

    <div class="errors">
      <p>firstname Errors:</p>
      <p ng-show="testForm.firstname.$error.required">firstname is required</p>
      <p ng-show="testForm.firstname.$error.minlength">firstname is too short</p>
      <p ng-show="testForm.firstname.$error.maxlength">firstname is too long</p>
    </div>              

    <label for="lastname">Last Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="lastname" ng-model="data.lastname" ng-required="true" ng-minlength="4" ng-maxlength="10">

    <div class="errors">
      <p>lastname Errors:</p>
      <p ng-show="testForm.lastname.$error.required">lastname is required</p>
      <p ng-show="testForm.lastname.$error.minlength">lastname is too short</p>
      <p ng-show="testForm.lastname.$error.maxlength">lastname is too long</p>
    </div>              


  <button class="button button-balanced" type="submit">Submit</button>

</ng-form>
```

Does anyone have a suggestion for what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: My open source module sorts this out, it also makes your html cleaner :-) http://jonsamwell.github.io/angular-auto-validate/

Answer (score 7):

You could use the built in attribute `$valid`:

```
<form name="testForm" novalidate ng-submit="testForm.$valid && submit()">
```

The submit function is called only when `testForm.$valid` is true.

I learnt it in this tutorial : https://www.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js .

Answer (score 1):

When you use `ng-submit`, the form will not be submitted to server directly. In `submit()` method you can decide whether to submit the form information to server or reject the submission. Check the form input controls validity then send the information to server side.

Comment: I don't believe that is the case.  It has nothing to do with submitting to the server.  The method in `ng-submit` is not supposed to be called at all if the form is not valid.

Comment: Believe it or not, ng-submit prevents the default action of submit button. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit. Add an if statement that check the form input controls validity and then do your task.

Comment: Weird I just remember this working differently.  I guess I was simply wrong.  Thanks for the clarification

Comment: @Alborz you did'nt read the doc entirely, It says that it prevent the default action **IF** the form does not contain action, data-action, or x-action attributes.